# Why compiler will not stop giving errors on this template code

Tags: c++, tuples, template-specialization

I am trying to understand why this code is permanently generating compilation errors, as to my understanding the template specialization should prevent the template expansion from going further as it hits INDEX = 0, and that should be the only recursion in the code.

```
template <typename STREAM, typename TUPLE, std::size_t INDEX> struct streamer {
  STREAM &operator()(STREAM &out, const TUPLE &tuple) {

    streamer<STREAM, TUPLE, INDEX - 1U> stream;
    return out << stream(out, tuple) << std::get<INDEX>(tuple);
  }
};

template <typename STREAM, typename TUPLE> struct streamer<0> {
  STREAM &operator()(STREAM &out, const TUPLE &tuple) {

    return out << std::get<INDEX>(tuple);
  }
};

template <typename STREAM, typename TUPLE>
STREAM &operator<<(STREAM &out, const TUPLE &tuple) {

  streamer<STREAM, TUPLE, std::tuple_size<TUPLE>::value - 1U> stream;
  return stream(out, tuple);
}

int main() {

  std::tuple<std::string, std::string> a_guy("name", "surname");
  std::cout << a_guy << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Please note the question is not about "how to print a tuple" as there are already plenty of those. The question is about why this specific code does not work, and specifically why does it make the compiler loop forever.

Comment: Please always include the errors also

Comment: You should pass all the template parameters when declaring a specialization. `struct streamer<0>` should be `streamer<STREAM, TUPLE, 0>` Also note that specialization does not have `INDEX` parameter
.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have syntax errors in you specialization, which is what the compiler tells you. Also, there is no parameter named `INDEX` in your specialization, which is another mistake. Correct syntax should be:

```
template <typename STREAM, typename TUPLE> struct streamer<STREAM, TUPLE, 0> {
//                                                         ^^^^^^  ^^^^^  
  STREAM &operator()(STREAM &out, const TUPLE &tuple) {

    return out << std::get<0>(tuple);
//                        ^^^
  }
};
```

There is another issue with your code:

`return out << stream(out, tuple) << std::get<INDEX>(tuple);`

This calls `operator<<(std::ostream&, std::ostream&)` which does't exist, but is not needed anyway. Just use `return stream(out, tuple) << std::get<INDEX>(tuple);`.

Comment: And this is why there is an endless loop, the first general form is always selected.

Comment: Thanks this has solved the main issue, namely the infinite loop. Unfortunately this code still does not work, as compiler complains about `std::tuple_size`:
`incomplete type ‘std::tuple_size<std::basic_ostream<char> >’ used in nested name specifier
   streamer<STREAM, TUPLE, std::tuple_size<TUPLE>::value - 1U> stream;`
I have tried to typename again `TUPLE` but it does not work.